# Hudson as passive server

Tags: hudson

Is it possible to use Hudson only as a passive server,i.e, not using it for building purpose instead sending build results generated by some other tool in maybe XML format and using Hudson to only display the results??

Comment: As you said in one comment, that you are basically using SCons. Did you check out the SCons plugin for Hudson? http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SCons+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very doable.

If it's running on the same machine, such as a cron job, check out http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Monitoring+external+jobs.

If you need to pull data from somewhere else, use a shell script as a build target, and do what you need to to stage the data locally (scp, etc.).

Comment: It's running on the same machine as of now but will be distributed once we get through this.. the problem I am facing is-- after setting the HUDSON_HOME path, I am running the python script that is used for building in the same console window, but how do I make Hudson know that it has to register this very build??

Comment: You can either schedule regular builds, or kick off a build manually by using curl or wget on http: //YOURHOST/hudson/job/PROJECTNAME/build.

Answer (score 1):

It may very well be possible using periodic builds and the URL SCM plug-in to pull in the xml files and the Plot Plug-in for display but more information is required before a more detailed answer can be provided.

What build tool are you currently using to generate build results?

Comment: it's basically scons but slightly modified to suit our industry needs..so not sure how to go about it..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of my Hudson jobs are just summaries and display information.  The 'jobs' need to run for data to be collected and saved.  The run could be based dependent jobs or just scheduled nightly.  Some examples:

- One of our jobs just merges together the .SER files from Cobertura and generates the Cobertura reports for an overall code coverage from all of our unit, integration and different types of system tests (hint for others doing the same: Cobertura has little logic for unsynchronized SER files.  Using them will yield some odd results.  There are some tweaks that can be done to the merge code that reduces the problem)
- Some of our builds write data to a database.  We have a once a week task that pulls the data from the database and creates an HTML file with trend charts.  The results are kept as part of the job.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me what you're describing is a plugin for Hudson.  For example, the CCCC plugin:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/CCCC+Plugin

It takes the output, in XML form, from the CCCC analyzer app and displays it in pretty ways in the Hudson interface.

Taking the same concept, you could write a plugin that works with the XML output from whatever build tool you have in mind and display it in Hudson.